How can I replace the anode rod with this in the way?
Including a picture but you can see the expansion tank is completely blocking removal of the anode rod. Is there another way to remove the anode rod?


Turn off the water and unscrew the tank from the pipe.  it's an inconvenience, but it's not a show stopper, you already need to turn the water off to replace the anode.
It seems that those tanks last about as long as the anode rods do. may as well replace both at the same time.

If the heater is more than a couple of years old, removing the expansion tank is going to be a walk in the park compared to the anode rod.

Yeah, you don't even need a wrench for the tank just spin it in the "downwards" direction.

You might be lucky if the anode is in segments, so you could pull it out.
Other than that you are out of luck and will have to remove the tank.

source

I've never done this, but couldn't one also pull the anode up a few inches, clamp it at its lowest point to hold it, saw it off above that point, lift the remaining anode up another few inches, repeat...

So long as you can source a sectional anode rod to replace it with, with sections that will allow it to be installed in the space available. You'll also need to be somewhat careful about where the waste from sawing goes.

@Ecnerwal I agree.  Perhaps the item described by user DIY75 can even be split further by hand into smaller sections while maintaining the integrity of the "wire".

OP might find the remains of the old anode aren't all that thick and can be bent.

yes, but how to get the new one in?

That was my thought.  Even if I spend the time necessary to cut a 3 foot anode rod every 6 inches, how do I get a replacement back in the tank?
I don't suppose there is any type of code violation, is there?   Not that it makes a difference as I took possession 3 years ago.

it would be tricky to partition a flexible rod further,  the flexible parts are that springy curtain wire stuff with plastic insulation to prevent short-circuiting the anode.
